# Sum of random variables definition

Tags: probability, random-variables

I know if I have two functions $f,g: A \to \mathbb{R}$, I can define the function sum $f+g:A \to \mathbb{R}$ as $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.

Given a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, a random variable is a (borel)-measurable function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

So given two random variables $X, Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ we can define the sum $X+Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

My question is, if I have two random variables, but defined on different probability spaces, can they still be sumed?  I ask because in the bibliography I see as they talk about sums of random variables without considering the base random space, but I can't understand how are they summed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be defined in some common probability space. Phrased differently, you need to know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ in order for the sum $X+Y$ (or any function $f(X,Y)$) to be meaningful.

The only exception (which is not really an exception) is if $X : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are also specified to be independent, which means that you should view both random variables as living in the common probability space $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ with the product measure.

Comment: You start saying "They need to be defined in some common probability space", but then convince me it is not that case, for example if  :Ω1→ℝ and :Ω2→ℝ are independent, then you see the sum defined on  Ω1×Ω2, which is not  Ω1 nor Ω2

Comment: @dami By that I mean that "$X : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are independent" is in some sense a shorthand for "$X : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$."

Comment: Sum of two random variables is defined iff  they are defined on the same probability space. Period. This has nothing to do with joint distributions. I do not see much meaning in this answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My life does not have much meaning either.